# Inequality: $2(p^2+q^2+r^2)+2(pq+qr+rp)\ge pqr$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I need to determine the range of $p,q,r$ such that $2(p^2+q^2+r^2)+2(pq+qr+rp)\ge pqr$. I am not given any other information except that $p,q,r\in \mathbb{R}$. I haven't solved a problem like this before, so I'm really stuck. I'm thinking that it might be true for all real numbers $p,q,r$ but then I would need a proof but I couldn't find one.

Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to add:

I wrote it as $(p+q)^2+(q+r)^2+(r+p)^2\ge pqr$.

Comment: Fix any two, say $p,q$. Then you have a quadratic condition on $r$ which is always satisfied for sufficiently large $|r|$, namely $2r^2+(2p+2q-pq)r+2(p^2+q^2+pq)\ge0$.

Comment: Your left hand side is a positive quadratic form, homogeneous degree 2. Right hand side degree 3. So, for any $(a,b,c)$ with $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + bc+ca+ab = 1,$ your inequality is true for $(p,q,r) = (ta,tb,tc)$ for positive $t$ up to some bound, then false for larger $t,$ this being for, say, $ abc > 0.$

Comment: Suggest you write it in spherical coordinates; for $xyz \leq 0$ the thing is just true, for $xyz >0,$ equating both sides allows one to solve for $\rho$ as a function of $\theta, \phi.$ In the end, the shape for which the inequality holds is a connected, infinite shape that includes four out of eight (closed) octants; put briefly, as a point gets near to (but not in) such a closed octant, $\rho$ goes to infinity.

Comment: In appearance, the full solution set is similar to that of $xyz \leq 1$

Comment: well, see if you can draw any sort of picture of $xyz=1,$ which is made up of four (identical) infinite pieces of surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me prove it for all $p,q,r \in (-1,\sqrt{3}-1)$.

First, if one or three of $p,q,r$ are nonpositive, it is clear the inequality holds.

Now consider $p,q,r$ are all positive. Then $|r| < 4$. Since for any $p,q$, $(p+q)^2\geq 4pq$.
It is clear that $$(p+q)^2+(p+r)^2+(q+r)^2\geq (p+q)^2\geq 4pq \geq pqr.$$

Next consider two of them are nonpositive. Without loss of generality, let $p\leq 0$ and $q\leq 0$. Again, the above argument holds.

---

The whole idea is using $(p+q)^2\geq 4pq$ which holds for any $p,q\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't hold true in general.
For example, let $p=q=r$, you will get $$12p^2\geq p^3.$$ You can see it is not true when $p>12$.

Comment: It will always hold if an odd number of $p,q,r$ are negative.

Comment: I have some sufficient conditions in mind now. For example, suppose they are all positive. If one of $p,q,r$ is less than or equal to 4, the claim holds. But yet not a necessary condition

Answer (score 1):

may be almagest 's suggestion is more general.

$ 2r^2+(2p+2q-pq)r+2(p^2+q^2+pq)\ge0$ will hold when

$(2p+2q-pq)^2-4*2*2(p^2+q^2+pq)\le 0 \iff (p^2-4p-12)q^2+(-4p^2-8p)q-12p^2 \le 0 \iff (p^2-4p-12)<0 \cap  (-4p^2-8p)^2+4*12p^2(p^2-4p-12) \le0 \iff -2<p<6 \cap -2 \le p \le4 \implies -2<p\le4$.

but when $p=-2$ it is also true for $\Delta_r <0 $.

so one of $p,q,r$ fall in $[-2,4]$, the inequality will hold. the other two have no limitation.